# Error al intentar capturar coordenada "Y" de MouseEvent en PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

Estoy realizando pruebas con PyQt6 para implementarlo en un proyecto desarrollado en Python y en la guía que estoy usando emplean la función QMouseEvent.y() pero me arroja el siguiente error:

"AttributeError: type object 'QMouseEvent' has no attribute 'y'"

La consola me indica que el error se dispara en el metodo que invoca la funcion:

```
def _calculate_clicked_value(self, e):
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        parent = self.parent()
        vmin, vmax = parent.minimum(), parent.maximum()
        d_height = self.size().height() + (self._padding * 2)
        step_size = d_height / self.n_steps
        x = int(self._padding) 
        size = int(step_size)       
        print("padding: " + str(x))
        print("size: " +str(size))
        print("posicion: "+ str(QtGui.QMouseEvent.position))
        click_y = e.y() - self._padding - step_size / 2

        pc = (d_height - click_y) / d_height
        value = vmin + pc * (vmax - vmin)
        self.clickedValue.emit(value)
```

Procedí a verificar la clase QMouseEvent pero me di cuenta que no posee ningún método X o Y los cuales si se reflejan en la documentación de PyQt6:

```
class QMouseEvent(QSinglePointEvent):

    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, type: QtCore.QEvent.Type, localPos: QtCore.QPointF, button: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, buttons: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, modifiers: QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier, device: typing.Optional['QPointingDevice'] = ...) -> None: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, type: QtCore.QEvent.Type, localPos: QtCore.QPointF, globalPos: QtCore.QPointF, button: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, buttons: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, modifiers: QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier, device: typing.Optional['QPointingDevice'] = ...) -> None: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, type: QtCore.QEvent.Type, localPos: QtCore.QPointF, scenePos: QtCore.QPointF, globalPos: QtCore.QPointF, button: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, buttons: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton, modifiers: QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier, device: typing.Optional['QPointingDevice'] = ...) -> None: ...

    def clone(self) -> typing.Optional['QMouseEvent']: ...
    def flags(self) -> QtCore.Qt.MouseEventFlag: ...
    def pos(self) -> QtCore.QPoint: ...
```

Quisiera saber si es un problema de instalación de PyQt6 o si ya alguno de esos métodos esta *Deprecated*. Estoy usando PyQt6 6.5.2 y Python 3.11.3 de 64 bits en Windows 11. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Deprecated" no significa que haya sido eliminado, si no que SERÁ eliminado.

##### De hecho, si fueron eliminados

Y... en realidad, estos métodos no aparecen en la documentación de pyqt6.

Por ejemplo, si miramos en la de [pyqt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtgui/qmouseevent.html), aparece esto:

> The functions pos(), x(), and y() give the cursor position relative to the widget that receives the mouse event.

Esto ya no aparece en [pyqt6](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtgui/qmouseevent.html), al igual que los métodos involucrados. A pesar de que aún se mencionan en una partecita abajo de todo.

Sinceramente, me parece raro que no hubiese habido un aviso de deprecated antes de la eliminación de los métodos (lo cual es lo habitual). O no revisé en la sección correcta, o eliminaron silenciosamente los métodos.

##### Con que se puede reemplazar

En la documentación de [pyside6](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QMouseEvent.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QMouseEvent.x) si dice que está deprecated y aconsejan usar `position().x()` y `position().y()` respectivamente.

##### Aclarando: algo a tener en cuenta en la busqueda de métodos

En realidad, que un método no aparezca en la clase no implica necesariamente su inexistencia.

En los lenguajes con Programación Orientada a Objetos (como Python y Java), existe algo llamado herencia. Esto es, la posibilidad de que una clase hija pueda heredar, justamente, los métodos de una clase padre.

Citando un ejemplo:

```
class Vehiculo:
    def mover(self, velocidad):
        ...

class Auto(Vehiculo):
    def tocar_bocina(self):
        ...
```

En este ejemplo, Auto posee tanto el método tocar_bocina como el que sería común para todos los vehiculos: mover.

Comment: Justo había encontrado que ahora pos() y position() son los que poseen el método y(). Ahora si se actualiza la posición del puntero. Muchas gracias.